# overlapping image and div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have the following html structure:

```
 <div class="gauge">
     <div id="user-follow-statistics">

     </div>
    <img src="{{ asset('bundles/shopiousmain/img/coming-soon.png') }}"/>
 </div>
```

I wanted this image to be positioned overlapping the `user-follow-statistics` div. How can I do that? As of now I tried making the position of the image as relative and setting top to -150px, but this seems to be a total hack and not clean. Any other way?

Comment: Can you show pictorially what you are asking for?

Comment: Make a fiddle for your problem.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/84cC3/1/

Comment: Looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/84cC3/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `img` to `position: relative;` and using `-` `top` value will reserve the space of the `img` physically on the document, instead set your container element i.e `.gauge` to `position: relative;` and than set the `img` to `position: absolute;`, now it is essential to set the container to `relative` else your `absolute` positioned element will flow out in the wild.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/84cC3/4/)

```
.gauge {
    position: relative;
}

.gauge img.coming_soon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

If you find any issue for the element stacking, use `z-index` for `.gauge img.coming_soon`

---

I've assigned a `class` to `img` tag. If you've a single `img` nested inside `.gauge` than you can also use `.gauge img` without declaring a `class` on the `img` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Set `position:absolute` for div `user-follow-statistics`.

```
#user-follow-statistics{
position:absolute;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/U2q6E/14/

Comment: tried changing it to absolute, the img now overlaps but it seems like it's hidden (meaning I can't see it)